# Casimir Effects in Small Hyperspherical Universes, Small Wormholes and Small Black Holes

Tags: quantum-field-theory, general-relativity, casimir-effect

If there was a path in the geometry of space-time that 'looped around', it seems like any particles (real or virtual) in the loop would have to match the periodic boundary conditions of that loop.

It also seems like that situation would be similar enough to the boundary conditions placed on virtual particles in a Casmir experiment that there would be less virtual possibilities and a lower vacuum energy density.

Is this the case and if so, what (if any) effect would this have back on this space-time geometry?  And if that was so, would it tend to cause expansion or contraction of that geometry?

Comment: You might find [this paper](https://arxiv.org/abs/hep-th/9608142) relevant.

Comment: Thanks!  That paper look pretty interesting.